# Bind to several class properties

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have some class with properties firstName and lastName. I want bind TextBlock to concatanation of this two properties. I know that I can create third property that will be return concatanation of these properties. But I dont want to use this approach. Is it possible to Bind TextBlock to two properties. and also I dont want create composite userControl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 3.5SP1, Microsoft added StringFormat to bindings. This makes it much easier. See [Lester's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) for an example. In your case:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0} {1}">
      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

or

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{1}, {0}">
      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use multibinding, but I guess that you have to code your way out of the concatanation.
Here is an example: [Multibinding](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings)

Comment: My shame. I dont know about Multibindings. Interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to bind to two properties, but there is not reason you cannot create two TextBlocks right?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding firstName}"/> <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastName}"/>
```

Comment: I can do this. But have a lot of textBlock on my form (about 200). It will boring to do this.

Comment: If it's that many, it will be boring anyways even if you can pack all the bindings into one TextBlock. Might as well come up with a code that will loop the whole thing and create the TextBlocks for for you. I'm not really that familiar with WPF, I would also be interested to know if there's any other better alternative to do this. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 0):

use either MultiBinding or Converter (if complex operation is there)